# WIX Toolset MSI. How to find the PGSQL dialog box?

Tags: postgresql, wix

I can't find where this window comes from in the Wix project. I did't find it in the project's.  I am using the default sets and a few dlls.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not a WiX dialog; it's part of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Where is it? How can it be changed?

Comment: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=psqlodbc.git